# Change select value to null if there is no data found on it

Tags: javascript, php, html

Guys I want to change the selected value into null if there is no data-quantity not found in the select field. For example I enter 10 on the quantity field There is no data-quantity = "10" in my select option tag so it should be null
and the total price should be equal to 0 . 
 [image]

Price of the item:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="price" id="price"class="price" value="<?php if($price!=""){echo $price;}else{echo $shop_item_orig_price;}?>">
```

Quantity:

```
<input type="number" name="quant" id="quant" /> // for example I enter 2
```

Shipping details:

```
<select name="shipment" disable>
 <option value="100"  data-quantity="1"> 100 per 1 item </option>
 <option value="150"  data-quantity="2"> 150 per 2 item </option> //this must be selected
</select>

<script>
function myFunction(quantInput)
{
  var price = document.getElementById("price");
  var quantity = document.getElementById("quant");
  var shipment = document.getElementById("shipmentSelect");
  var total = document.getElementById("total");
    $("#shipmentSelect").find("option[data-quantity=" + quantInput + "]").attr('selected', 'selected').siblings().removeAttr('selected');
  var shipmentValue = shipment.value;
  salePrice = price.value;
  var totalPrice = (salePrice*quantInput) + parseInt(shipmentValue);
  total.value = totalPrice;
}
</script>
```

Total Price:

```
<input id="total" name="answer" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:5px;"readonly />
```

Comment: can you create a FIDDLE?

Comment: Why wouldn't you allow 10? Is there a limit? 10 would be 5 orders of 2 quantities.

Comment: Also, having javascript to indicate what is not allowed can be good, but you should check this on the server side. A good number of people who are web developers know how to bypass javascript security.

Comment: of course ... i can check it im using codeigniter for it :) im user html5 validation for frontend validation

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like

```
<input type="number" name="quant" value="" id="quant" />
<select name="shipment" class="select_custom" disable>
    <option value="100"  data-quantity="1"> 100 per 1 item </option>
    <option value="150"  data-quantity="2"> 150 per 2 item </option> //this must be selected
</select>

<input type="hidden" name="price" id="price"class="price" value="<?php if($price!=""){echo $price;}else{echo $shop_item_orig_price;}?>">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#quant").focusout(function () {
            var qty = $(this).val();
            var price = $("#price").val();
            $(".select_custom option").each(function () {
                console.log($(this).attr('data-quantity'));
                if ($(this).attr('data-quantity') == qty) {
                    $("#quant").val(qty);
                    $("#price").val(price);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $("#quant").val(0);
                    $("#price").val(0);
                    $(".select_custom").append('<option value=null selected>Null</option>').selectmenu('refresh');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

check working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urfusion/n01sy7ap/)